# Java, JVM internals

Tags: java, jvm

1. I am running Eclipse, Tomcat, a servlet based webapplication my windows 10 machine. I was wondering how many JVM instances will be created?
2. Also, When will JVM be instantiated in windows 10 on startup or on starting any java based app.

Comment: It will be two: a. One for eclipse. b. One for tomcat. Assuming your servlet application is deployed within the tomcat container. JVM gets instantiated when you start a java based app, not on windows startup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. One per process. See the Processes tab of your Task Manager.
2. When starting a JVM process (typically once per app, but could be more if it forks).